# Regex Option in C# and Regex in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I learn about regular expression, and i have two quastions;

1. I saw, that I can define an options to the regex, but i don't succes to understand whah are the ECMAScript, CultureInvariant and ExplicitCapture options, can anyone explain in simply words and give an example to aforementioned options?
2. in visual studio, can replce and find by regex, but the syntax of vs differents from the syntax that regex object uses,does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExplicitCapture` makes all parentheses non-capturing unless you use named captures. This can make regexes a bit more readable because you can write `(...)` where you otherwise would have had to write `(?:...)` to make a non-capturing group.

The downside, of course, is that if you *do*  want to capture part of the match, you have to write `Name: (?<name>.*)` instead of `Name: (.*)`, for example.

`ECMAScript` causes the regex engine to behave like an ECMASCript (e. g., JavaScript) regex engine, which means dropping a lot of regex features of the .NET regex engine - but it allows you to use JavaScript regexes unchanged.

`CultureInvariant` tells the regex engine to ignore cultural differences in case matching. For example, in Turkish, the uppercase version of `i` is not `I` as it is in English, but `İ`, so a culture-sensitive, case-insensitive match of `i` would not match `I` on a Turkish system.

You might want to check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0sbec17.aspx) and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk2wykcz%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more info on this.